# Apache proxy rewrite to https://my.domain.fr/ when status is 404

Tags: linux, apache, reverse-proxy, centos7

I need you help please.
I have an httpd reverse proxy and I need to redirect everything that return 404 status to the main page.

I have configured my vhost file like this:

````
   ```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=404]
    #ErrorDocument 404 http://%{HTTP_HOST}/
````

But I does not working.
Instead of returning the main page It return this message:

```
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

ps: I don't use htaccess file I just want to make it work using vhost file.
Can you help me please ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Apache does not rewrite HTTP responses. You must modify the proxied application.

Comment: what do I have to modify exactly ?

Comment: The application that is generating the HTTP 404 response.